# Python pandas crosscentury dates after 2digit year correction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a pandas dataframe where I had to correct the dates from 2year digits to 4year digits. 
As pandas interprets 2digit years below 69 as 2000s, a lot of my cross-centutry data is now 100 years in the future. 
I tried this:

```
centurymask = df['from'] > '2021'
century_correction = df['from'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(years=100))
df['from'].where(centurymask, century_correction)
```

,but with no success, as the - operator is not supported. I am certain the solution is close, but somehow can't figure it out.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up using numpys relativedelta

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

like

```
df.loc[df['from'] > '2021', 'from'] = df['from'] - np.timedelta64(100,'Y')
```